# How to open Dalvik .dex files and get the Dalvik byte code of the application from apk format

Tags: android

How can I open Android .dex files?  How to get the Dalvik byte code of the application from the apk format?

I need to apply some algorithm on the Dalvik byte code of the application. Therefore I need to get a readable form of the Dalvik byte code of the application. How can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dedexer](http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/), to disassemble the `.dex` file into dalvik bytecode (`.ddx`).